# How to pass a variable from one php block of code to another in one single page?

Tags: php, database, variables

I am getting error to this probably, `$result = mysql_query("Select setyear, YearName from tblset, tblyear where tblyear.ID=tblset.setyear group by setyear having tblset.setcours=".$res, $connection);`

I want to pass the value of `select name="studcourse" class="form-control`"** which is in variable *$res* and put it on the *$result* variable under **`select name="studyear" class="form-control`".

Can anybody help me?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['$PHP_SELF'];?>">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Student Course</label> 
<select name="studcourse" class="form-control">

   <?php
     $result = mysql_query("Select setcours, course_desc from tblset, tbl_coursetype where tbl_coursetype.course_no=tblset.setcours group by setcours", $connection);

     if (!$result) {
     die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
     }
     // 4. Use returned data
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
     echo "<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[1]}</option>";  
     }
  ?>

  <?php
  $res="";
  $res=$_POST["studcourse"];
  ?>
</select> 
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Student Year</label> 
<select name="studyear" class="form-control">

  <?php
     $result = mysql_query("Select setyear, YearName from tblset, tblyear where tblyear.ID=tblset.setyear group by setyear having tblset.setcours=".$res, $connection);
     if (!$result) {
     die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
     }
     // 4. Use returned data
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
     echo "<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[1]}</option>";  
     }
?>
</select> 
</div>
```

Comment: You want to put what? You already put that value into `$res`. Please explain again.

Comment: Just simply, I want to get totally the result from **select name="studcourse" class="form-control"** and compare it to the syntax here, `$result = mysql_query("Select setyear, YearName from tblset, tblyear where tblyear.ID=tblset.setyear group by setyear having tblset.setcours=".$res, $connection);` but I will not appear any output. Maybe because of an error occurred and I don't know where to fix it.

Comment: What error are you getting right now?

Comment: `$res` is from here, **select name="studcourse" class="form-control"**. And I want to compare it to the `$result` code inside another <div class> but it is not working.

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to use the value of the first select menu `studcourse` to populate the second dropdown menu `studyear`? Incidentally there is a minor error `$_SERVER['$PHP_SELF']` should be `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: Yes. But it doesnt work. @RamRaider

Answer (score 0):

You can pass one variable to another php using session variables :

```
<? Php 
session_start(); 
$z=3;
$_SESSION['var_name'] =$z;? >
```

Second php :

```
<? Php
session_start() ;
$x=$_SESSION['var_name'] ;? >
```

Comment: How? Can you site an example if it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `<?php $res ?>` before starting html code as

```
<?php 
$res = '';
if($_POST['studcource']){
$res = $POST['studcource'];
}

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['$PHP_SELF'];?>">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Student Course</label>
<select name="studcourse" class="form-control" onchange="document.form.submit();">
<?php
 $result = mysql_query("Select setcours, course_desc from tblset, tbl_coursetype where tbl_coursetype.course_no=tblset.setcours group by setcours", $connection);

 if (!$result) {
 die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
 }
 // 4. Use returned data
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
 echo "<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[1]}</option>";  
 }  ?>
</select> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Student Year</label> 
<select name="studyear" class="form-control">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("Select setyear, YearName from tblset, tblyear where tblyear.ID=tblset.setyear group by setyear having tblset.setcours=".$res, $connection);
 if (!$result) {
 die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
 }
 // 4. Use returned data
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
 echo "<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[1]}</option>";  
 }
?>
</select> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance if this is not what you meant but I interpreted the question to mean that you wish to populate the second dropdown menu based upon the selection made in the first dropdown menu. To that end ( not tested ) the approach below implements ajax to send a POST request to the same page that is then used in the sql query. The results of the sql query are then used to generate the options for the second dropdown menu...

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['studcourse'] ) ){
        /* Generate the html and send to javascript callback to insert into select menu */
        @ob_clean();

        $studcourse=mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['studcourse'] );
        /*
            Possible alternative SQL
            ------------------------
            select s.`setyear`, yr.`YearName`
                from `tblset` s
                left outer join `tblyear` yr on yr.`id`=s.`setyear`
                where s.`setcours`='".$studcourse."'
                order by s.`setyear`;
        */
        $sql="select `setyear`, `YearName` 
                from `tblset`, `tblyear` 
                where `tblyear`.`ID`=`tblset`.`setyear` 
                group by `setyear` 
                having `tblset`.`setcours`='".$studcourse."';";

        $result=mysql_query( $sql, $connection );

        if( $result ){
            while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) { 
                echo "<option value='{$row[0]}'>{$row[1]}";
            }
        } else {
            echo '<option>No results';  
        }
        exit(); 
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example - set select menu based upon value from previous select menu</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

            function cbstudyear(r){
                document.getElementById('studyear').innerHTML=r;
            }

            function setstudyear( event ){
                var el=typeof( event.target )!='undefined' ? event.target : event.srcElement;
                var value=el.options[ el.options.selectedIndex ].value;
                var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
                var headers={
                    'Accept': "text/html, application/xml, application/json, text/javascript, "+"*"+"/"+"*"+"; charset=utf-8",
                    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                };
                req.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( req.readyState==4 ) {
                       if( req.status==200 ) cbstudyear.call( this, req.response );
                       else console.warn( 'Error: '+req.status+' status code returned' );
                    }
                }
                req.open( 'POST', document.location.href, true );
                for( header in headers ) req.setRequestHeader( header, headers[ header ] );
                req.send( 'studcourse=' + value );
            }
        </script>
    </html>
    <body>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Student Course</label> 
                <select name="studcourse" id='studcourse' class="form-control" onchange='setstudyear(event)'>
                <?php
                    $result = mysql_query("select `setcours`,`course_desc` 
                                            from `tblset`, `tbl_coursetype` 
                                            where `tbl_coursetype`.`course_no`=`tblset`.`setcours`
                                            group by `setcours`;", $connection );

                    if( $result ){
                        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {  
                            echo "<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[1]}";  
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<option>Database query failed";
                    }
                ?>
                </select> 
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Student Year</label> 
            <select name="studyear" id='studyear' class="form-control">
            </select> 
        </div>
        <!--
            Other form elements here presumably ~ including submit button etc
        -->
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the effort. I'm a little bit confused about the code, probably because I'm just a beginner about this. But let me give you an example if it is okay with you but it's okay if you don't mind these, just saying in advance. Okay, for an instance in the first dropdown, there are 2 courses, let say BSIT(1st year and 2nd year) and BSED(3rd year and 4th year). On the second dropdown, it should only appear the year level of the choosen course. But in my case, I don't know how to do that. I got a lot of codes tried, but it doesn't working.

Comment: If I will remove `having tblset.setcours=".$res` inside this code, `$result = mysql_query("Select setyear, YearName from tblset, tblyear where tblyear.ID=tblset.setyear group by setyear having tblset.setcours=".$res, $connection);` the second dropdown will appear 4 year levels, where in fact I only choose one course that has 2 year levels.

Comment: The moment that I will choose a course, it will also generate the year levels as to what year level that the course have.

Comment: I'm curious about why you used `having` rather than a more standard `where` clause in your sql. I would suggest that you use a `mySQL` gui, such as `HEIDI` to test your sql statements to make sure you can retrieve the results you need and then build the form and functions around the sql that you know works. Sadly I'm a little unclear as to your exact requirements - have you tried the code above ( has been updated recently ) to see what happens when you select an item from the first dropdown menu?